# How to delete pointers that are passed as arguments in function calls C++

Tags: c++, pointers

edit: I changed the example and tried to clarify what I'm doing.

I have a recursive function that takes a pointer to an array as an argument, creates a pointer to a smaller array, and calls itself, passing the smaller array as an argument

```
int ListOfNumbers::recursiveQuickselect(int *array, int arrayLen){
   if(arrayLen > 10){
     int *tempArray;
     tempArray = new int[some value];

     ...edit tempArray....

     return recursiveQuickselect(tempArray, tempArrayLen);
   }
   else{
       //base case:
       sort this small array and return an element from it
   }
```

When I run valgrind I am told that 1 block is lost in the function recursiveQuickselect.

where do I delete tempArray in this code?

If I delete it before the call then I'm passing nothing into the function

I obviously can't delete it after the return statement.

NOTE: I cannot use vectors, this is a school assignment that does not allow them.

Comment: That idea with the extra `median` variable is in fact the correct way to do it ... if you absolutely must use `new[]` and `delete[]`, thus creating these problems for yourself.

Comment: For the use case you describe, tempArray needn't be a pointer at all. just pass the ref to it through getMedian. This will be evaluated, a result gleaned, and the original variable will go out of scope. No heap allocation needed.

Comment: @dwerner would you mind elaborating on passing the ref? I don't understand what you mean. I also changed the example to better illustrate my problem.

Comment: The important question here is if the size of `tempArray` is know beforehand or not. In the first case you do not need a dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass the address of a dynamically sized array to a function, but
want automatic cleanup of the dynamic memory since you have no way to delete
the memory. Like many commented, that's exactly what `std::vector` does, e.g.
in your example

```
ListOfNumbers::medianOfFivePivot(int *array, int arrayLen){
   std::vector<int> tempArray(tempArrayLen);

   // ...edit tempArray....

   return getMedian(&tempArray[0], tempArrayLen);
```

Comment: I cannot use vectors, I edited the question. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: The school is *REALLY* behind the times; vector has been in every C++ standard including the first one back in the previous century. Don't pick up any more bad habits from that professor. Having said that, the best solution often is to write a simple vector-like class to wrap `new[]/delete[]`

Answer (score 0):

How about you `delete` the memory in `getMedian`? If `getMedian` is recursive, just delete in the base case.

Or (@Havenard), you can store the value of `getMedian()` delete the memory and then return the value.

C++ supplies `std::vector` so you do not have to deal with memory management, why not use those instead?

Comment: This is for a class so I must use arrays. But yes my real problem is in fact passing pointers to recursive functions! however inside the function, because the pointer is defined by the header, I never call new. Do I call delete[] on the pointer defined in the method header?

Comment: @user3304376 Correct, call `delete []` on the pointer inside the function

Comment: This is highly irregular. The function that allocated the memory should be responsible of disposing it.

Answer (score -1):

you should just be able to

```
delete[] tempArray;
```

If that doesn't work then I really don't understand the question.

Edit: Place the delete[] line right before return

Comment: I know how to delete it, I am wondering when to do so, if I delete it after the return statement then it never gets deleted.

Comment: correct, because return stops the function and transfers control back to the caller. do it right above the return. updating answer

Comment: `return` stops the function and you cannot `delete` after it, you have to `delete` before you `return`. Either that or use `std::vector` instead of arrays, so the compiler will take care of disposing it automatically.

Comment: @awesomeyi Just save the result of `getMedian()` somewhere, delete tempArray, then return the value you just saved...

Comment: there isn't any need to use vectors in this.

Comment: @phyrrus9: If you don't want to manually delete in `getMedian` there's no way around some RAII container which cleans up automatically. Deleting before is most definitely wrong since one then passes a pointer to delete memory to the function which might use it (definitely big nono).